# TableView reload data troubles

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a function which creates a few arrays and fills them with data. I execute this function from `viewDidLoad`.

In the function I add `[self.tableview reloadData];`

I set breakpoints etc and it doesn't even go to `numberOfRowsInTableView` etc. Should `[self.tableview reloadData]` execute all the table view functions so it appears on the iPhone screen?

** UPDATE **

Firstly the function is called :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    ViewController *GetDeals = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [GetDeals TopDealsRecieve:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DeviceToken"]];

    [self.tableview setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableview setDataSource:self];

    [self.tableview reloadData];
```

The function TopDealsRecieve gets the arrays like this :

```
 NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
        allLogos = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"logo"];
        allcontent = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"content"];
        allpostode = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"postcode"];
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)allcontent.count);
        allname = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"name"];
        alladdress = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"address"];
        alladdress2 = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"address2"];
        alllat = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"lat"];
        alllong = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"lng"];
        // refresh the table view
        [self.tableview setDelegate:self];
        [self.tableview setDataSource:self];
        [self.tableview reloadData];
```

and in :

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   NSLog(@"wnks %lu",(unsigned long)allcontent.count);
   return allcontent.count;

}
```

All the variables are available all throughout my code and they are assigned like this :

```
// global var

NSArray *alllocationsID;
NSArray *alllocationsCity;
NSArray *allLogos;
NSArray *allcontent;
NSArray *allpostode;
NSArray *allname;
NSArray *alladdress;
NSArray *alladdress2;
NSArray *alllat;
NSArray *alllong;
```

At the top of the ViewController. 
This did work when the GetArray function wasn't a function and it was just placed in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: Make sure your datasource and delegate are hooked up to your `UITableView`

Comment: <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, is added to my view controller.h file

Comment: yes it will call methods. make sure you have implemented Delegate & Datasource Perfectly

Comment: Did you connect Datasource And Delegate From Xib or Storyboard?

Comment: If you are not using a `UITableViewController` then you must actually set the `delegate` and `dataSource` properties of your table view.

Comment: Did you write `self.tableView.delegate = self` and `self.tableView.dataSource = self`?

Comment: I am using external arrays for this. I have one function that brings out all the data and assigns it to arrays. I then use tableview reload data. I then have all the rest of the functions like NumberOfRows etc.. If i put the code in viewDidLoad then it works fine.

Comment: It looks like you're calling `GetDealsReceive` on some other view controller called `GetDeals`, which is not your current view controller (which would be called `self`).

Comment: No Aaron, I am calling a function on the viewcontroller which is my current view controller and the function is TopDealsRecieve

Answer (score 1):

You should to add these 2 lines to your method `viewDidload` before to execute `[self.tableview reloadData];` like this

```
[self.tableview setDelegate:self];
[self.tableview setDataSource:self];

[self.tableview reloadData];
```

Comment: it seems that numberOfRowsInSection function starts immediately but when i do a reload it doesn't go back to it.

Comment: Are you checking you are not setting the number of sections to 0??

Comment: -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   NSLog(@"wnks %lu",(unsigned long)allcontent.count);
   return allcontent.count;
    
}

Comment: it is 0 yes because it runs the first time around when no data is loaded. when the data function starts I use reload data and delegate=self and it doesn't go back to it.

Comment: [self.tableview setDelegate:self]; and [self.tableview setDataSource:self]; and if you do after [self.tableview reloadData] and your methods will be called

Comment: You should call to reloadData after to have your arrays with data filled. So when you have your array allcontent filled, call to reloadData method. Are you implementing other method like numberOfSectionsInTableView:??? check that you are not returning 0

Comment: Done that Son and it still doesn't work. I am returning 0 on numberofrowsinsection as it seems to go straight to that, but when i enter reloadtableview it doesn't go back to it.